# When exactly should we perform spell correction in the text pre-processing pipeline?

Tags: python, nlp, data-science, recommendation-engine

Does the step for correcting spellings of words have to be done before Lexicon normalization(i.e. stemming, lemmatization) or after? If we do it after lexicon normalization, wouldn't the words already be reduced to their root form if we perform lemmatization?(By passing the POS i.e. Parts Of Speech tag of the word as an argument) so there wouldn't be any use for spell checking after lexicon normalization right?

Comment: Lemmatisation on misspelled words won't be very efficient. IMO first spelling correction should be done and then lemmatisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should correct spelling 1st. Lemmatization is trained on some corpus but since I introduced something which not part of that it may not work.  see below:

```
# import these modules 
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer 
  
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer() 
  
print("changing :", lemmatizer.lemmatize("changing", pos ="v")) 
print("change :", lemmatizer.lemmatize("change")) 
print("changer :", lemmatizer.lemmatize("changer")) 
  
# # a denotes adjective in "pos" 
print("changing :", lemmatizer.lemmatize("changyng", pos ="v"))
```

---

```
changing : change #<----------
change : change
changer : changer
changing : changyng #<-------
```

look I have just changed the spelling of changing to changyng and it was not able to perform the lemmatization.